# Show that $f$ maps the unit circle to itself

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the complex mapping defined by $$f_a(z)=\frac{z-a}{\bar az-1}$$ for some constant $a.$ I want to show that $f$ maps the unit circle to itself. I know that the unit circle is defined by $|z|=1,$ or equivalently $z=e^{i \theta}.$ This gives me $$f_a(z)=f_a(e^{i \theta})=\frac{e^{i \theta}-a}{\bar a e^{i \theta}-1}$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here though.

Additional question: I also want to show that of $a$ lies inside the unit disk then $f$ maps the unit disk to itself. In order to answer this I have shown that $$|\bar a z-1|^2 - |z-a|^2 =(1-|a|^2)(1-|z|^2)<1$$

How am I able to use this to deduce the result?

Comment: What you want is $1 - \lvert f(z)\rvert^2 = 0$ if $\lvert z\rvert = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Note that $\overline{e^{i \theta}-a}=
-e^{-i\theta}(\overline{a}e^{i\theta}-1)$ implies that $|e^{i \theta}-a|=|\overline{a}e^{i\theta}-1|$.

P.S. As regards your additional question, if $|z|<1$ and $|a|<1$ then
$$|\bar a z-1|^2-|z-a|^2=(\bar a z-1)( a \bar z-1)-(z-a)(\bar z-\bar a)=|a|^2|z|^2+1-|z|^2-|a|^2\\=(1-|a|^2)(1-|z|^2).$$
Hence (note that $\bar a z\not=1$),
$$1 - \frac{|z-a|^2}{|\bar a z-1|^2} =\frac{(1-|a|^2)(1-|z|^2)}{|\bar a z-1|^2}>0$$
which implies that 
$$\left|\frac{z-a}{\bar a z-1}\right|^2<1$$
that is $|f(z)|<1$.

Comment: There is an extension to this question that I'm interested in, should I ask it here or ask a new question?

Comment: @user332597 What is the question?

Comment: I've added it to my post.

Comment: @user332597 See my edited post. Any further doubt?

Comment: I think that clears it up now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
|f_a(e^{i\theta})| &= \left|\frac{e^{i\theta}-a}{\bar{a}e^{i\theta}-1}\right|\\
&= \left|\frac{1}{-e^{i\theta}}\right| \left|\frac{e^{i\theta}-a}{e^{-i\theta}-\bar{a}}\right|\\
&=1\cdot \frac{|e^{i\theta}-a|}{\left|\overline{e^{i\theta}-a}\right|}\\
&=1
\end{align*}

Comment: + the maximum modulus principle, and the fact $f'(z) \ne 0$ ?  (I think the OP meant the unit disk)